# Python equivalent of Ruby's expression: "puts x += value"

Tags: python, ruby, language-comparisons

For curiosity's sake...

In Ruby:

```
=>$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > puts x = 2
2
 => nil 
1.8.7 :002 > puts x += 2 while x < 40
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
```

It's quite handy.

Is it possible to do that in Python in a single line and if yes how?

Comment: I don't know ruby, but I'd like to learn someday (so forgive my ignorance) -- How is this different than `range(4,40,2)`?  Or an equivalent generator function?

Comment: the key here is that as others have answered, ruby allows to run a statement as an expression, so more stuff can be done in less space. I was wondering if it was possible to achieve a similar thing in python, just for the sake of curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you can not do *exactly* or *very similarly* the same in Python is because **in Ruby, everything is expression**.

Python distincts between statements and expressions and only expressions can be evaluated (therefore printed, I mean passed to print operator/function).

So such code cannot be done in Python in that form you showed us. Everything you can do is to find some "similar" way to write down statement above as a Python expression but it will definitely not be that "Rubyous".

*IMHO, in Python, impossibility of such behaviour (as described in this use case), nicely follows "explicit is better than implicit" Zen of Python rule.*

Comment: The first two pharagraphs of your answer explained it all.

I'm not trying to find a "Rubyous" way to do something in Python, I just find comparing the two languages quite instructive. Is there a way to achieve the same loop in one line in python? I never use that kind of expressions in python, but as far as I know I can't do that in python, so I was wondering if it would be possible somehow.

Comment: Not sure I understand your ZoP reference. What's implicit about the given code?

Answer (score 2):

a one-liner to produce the same result:

```
for x in xrange(4,42,2): print x
```

gives:

```
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
```

[xrange](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) is a built in function that returns an “xrange object”, which yields the next item without storing them all (like `range` does), this is very similar to OP's `while` loop.

Comment: "for i in xrange(4,42,2): print i" also

Comment: @nemesisdesign even better :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in python; you can't use a statement (`x += 2`) as an expression to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

With the remarks about assigment not being expressions in Python on the other answers kept,
one can do this in Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function

[print(x) for x in range(0,42,2)]
```